# How can I modify the Direct Stochastic Simulation Algorithm of Gillespy2 (https://github.com/StochSS/GillesPy2) to Sample the Product Stoichiometry?

Tags: python

I am currently using Gillespy2 to simulate stochasticity in chemical reactions. The specific algorithm is the direct method, whose outline is as follows ([Gillespie, 2007](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev.physchem.58.032806.104637)):

0. Initialize the time t = t0 and the system’s state x = x0.
1. With the system in state x at time t, evaluate all the aj(x) and their sum a0(x).
2. Generate values for τ and j using Equations 10a,b (or their equivalent).
3. Effect the next reaction by replacing t ← t + τ and x ← x + νj.
4. Record (x, t) as desired. Return to Step 1, or else end the simulation.

In some of my reactions, the value of the propensity, aj(x), is a function of the number of products generated, vj, which follows a probability distribution. I was thinking of incorporating a step between 0 and step 1 where a random sample will be generated to be used for that iteration and that will enable me to specify a specific value for aj(x) and vj for each of the iteration. Thank you!

At first, I tried to alter at least the product number. I thought of defining the product number of the reaction to be a random sample from the geometric distribution. However, it seems that the sampling is only done once at the very start and the same is used throughout the whole simulation.

```
# Reactions
r1 = gillespy2.Reaction(
    name='r1', rate='k1',
    reactants={}, products={'M': np.random.geometric(0.5, size = None)} %this is where I tried it
)
model.add_reaction([r1])
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.